# Detect when finger leaves mouse during scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have an Apple mouse which has no scroll wheel. I want to detect when my finger leaves the surface of the mouse during scrolling. This is not the same thing as mouseup, as no mouse button has been pressed. I've seen Stackoverflow deal with similar questions with responses indicating touchstart, touchmove and touchend. But I couldn't get touchstart or touchmove to work and am not even sure if these are the events I am looking for.

And another issue is how do I deal with mice that do have a scroll wheel? If the user scrolls the wheel and then lets go, does the same api also detect when their finger is no longer scrolling?

Keep in mind that I want to detect WHEN the finger leaves the mouse and NOT when scrolling comes to an end.

Comment: Touch events relate to devices that implement [*touch event APIs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) like touch pads and screens. If the Apple Magic Mouse supports touch events then you'll see them, but it would be very unusual to dispatch a touch event every time the user touched their virtual mouse wheel.

Comment: Currently there is no such device that provides JS information if your user is touching mouse (or even it's buttons).